# ViewFlipper Layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper

I have defined a view flipper like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/Heading001" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="105dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:text="XXX" android:textSize="25sp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectanglefield" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvLongName" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Heading001"
            android:text="XXX" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:typeface="normal" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvUsage" android:layout_below="@+id/tvLongName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Heading001" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" android:text="R"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvCardinality"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false" android:layout_below="@+id/tvLongName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvUsage" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="(0..1)" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvDatatype" android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="XX" android:textColor="#000000" android:background="@drawable/rectanglewhite"
            android:textSize="25dp" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Heading001" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp">
            <include android:id="@+id/flipperView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/detail_item_view02" />
            <include android:id="@+id/flipperView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/detail_item_view01" />
        </ViewFlipper>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The flipperView01 view is then defined like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvNotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" 
        android:text="abcdef ef abcdef abcdef " 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I have is that I would like the TextView in the "flipperView01" to be the full width of the dialog, currently it is not is is only very narrow

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the full layout where the `ViewFlipper` is used?

Comment: Full layout now included within the question

Comment: Remove the `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Heading001"` from the `ViewFlipper`.

Comment: @Luksprog that did it, make it an answer and I'll credit you with the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem remove the `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Heading001"` property from the `ViewFlipper` as that will align the right margin of the `ViewFlipper` with the *Heading001* `TextView`'s right margin(and that `TextView` has a limited dimension).

Also regarding your layout:

- the `layout_weight` is useless in a `RelativeLayout`
- you should use the `@+id/theId` notation only for the first occurrence of that id in the layout, in the next places where you would use the `id` you would simply use `@id/theId`

Comment: Are you certain about that last point?  As a rule, I use `@+id` everywhere.  That way, if I end up shuffling the order of elements in an XML file, it doesn't matter which element mentions an id first.  (It's especially useful when using `RelativeLayout`, for example.)

Comment: @ToddSjolander Well, the official guide for the `RelativeLayout` follows this convention http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html . And I would go with the style used by the Android engineers.

Comment: @Luksprog I certainly don't doubt that it works the way you stated, and it's fair to assume that this is how the Android engineers designed it to be used.  I started off doing each one that way, then accidentally left in the "+" and noticed that it still worked.  Now I just put it in everywhere I use an `id` as a convenience for when I end up reordering Views inside a `RelativeLayout`.  Hopefully it's not a bug they intend to correct.  I see it as a feature, or maybe a happy side effect.

Comment: @ToddSjolander I doubt is a bug and the `@+id` notation will stand because the `RelativeLayout` needs only to find those views with those ids(which will happen with no problems). If I'm not mistaken even the graphical editor in `Eclipse` throws drag and dropped views only with the `@+id` notation. I use the notation from my answer because if I switch views in the `RelativeLayout` and put `@id` first, `Lint` will complain and I want to see this as it will make me be more careful on how I further change the relations between the views. But you could go either ways in the end.